# slice a list of strings from index[0] till random index

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to slice a list of strings from index[0] till a random index. 
The index number where the slicing needs to end, is always at the index number that holds a "(".
The code i'm trying is as follow

```
new_name = [[:x:] if x == "(" else x for x in new_name]
```

I always get invalid syntax error.
How can i make this work?

thx in advance

Comment: `[:x:]` why is this?

Comment: due to the fact that i don't know on what index number the "(" is, i thought that i could use x as an replacing value for the index number

Comment: Please [`upvote and accept`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if any of the solutions provided your required result.

Answer (score 1):

The `x` variable in the `for` expression is assigned to each character in `new_name` for each iteration, not the index of each character.

For your purpose you should simply use the `str.find()` method to get the index of a given character in a string:

```
new_name = new_name[:new_name.find('(')]
```

Answer (score 0):

List Comprehension method:

```
l = list('sandeep(Kadapa)')

[i for i in iter(lambda x=iter(l): next(x),'(')]

['s', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'p']
```